# Error "Could not find com.huawei.hms:location:6.0.0.302" while adding Huawei Kits

Tags: android, android-studio, maven, gradle, huawei-mobile-services

Following [agc-get-started-android](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started-android-0000001058210705) and having

Project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'

    }
}
```

App module build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:6.0.0.302'
}
```

Gradle build ends with error below:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.huawei.hms:location:6.0.0.302.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/hms/location/6.0.0.302/location-6.0.0.302.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/huawei/hms/location/6.0.0.302/location-6.0.0.302.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/huawei/hms/location/6.0.0.302/location-6.0.0.302.pom
 Required by:
     project :app
```

What is the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could follow [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/integrate-as-sdk-0000001050168936?ha_source=hms1) to integrate.

Add the AppGallery Connect plugin and the Maven repository.

- Go to **buildscript > repositories** and configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK.
- Go to **allprojects > repositories** and configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK.
- If the **agconnect-services.json** file has been added to the app, go to **buildscript > dependencies** and add the AppGallery Connect plugin configuration.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK.
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        // Add the AppGallery Connect plugin configuration. You are advised to use the latest plugin version.
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK.
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
}
```

In Gradle 7.0 or later, configuration under **allprojects > repositories** is migrated to the project-level **settings.gradle** file.

The following is a configuration example of the **settings.gradle** file:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() 
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to try [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DbUJ.png) and [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94P4j.png).